# Fetching data from dynamic rows added in footer of grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I am working on an app in which I have added a repeater control and within it I have added a `Grid View` Because I need to show separate grids based on data fetched from db. So data is grouped on the bases of dates and split into grids. Now I have another BUTTON attached with each grid. IF user clicks that it would add new row to that particular grid view. Let suppose user clicks two times two new rows are added. The problem I am facing is fetching the values from that row being added. As the rows are not yet part of grid so `row.count()` gives me only count till existing row. So any solution how to fetch values . Here's the code:

```
   private void CreateExtraFooter(GridView grdview, List<Employee> list, int NoOfFooter_rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NoOfFooter_rows; i++)
        {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(i, i, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Normal);

        #region Eachrow
        TableCell cell0 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell0);
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell2);
        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell3);
        TableCell cell4 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell4);
        TableCell cell5 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell5);
        TableCell cell6 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell6);
        TableCell cell7 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell7);
        TableCell cell8 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell8);
        TableCell cell9 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell9);
        TableCell cell10 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell10);
        TableCell cell11 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell11);
        TableCell cell12 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell12);
        TableCell cell13 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell13);
        TableCell cell14 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell14);
        TableCell cell15 = new TableCell(); row.Cells.Add(cell15);

        DropDownList ddlSalesRep_F = new DropDownList();
        ddlSalesRep_F.ID = "ddlSalesRep_F";

        ddlSalesRep_F.DataSource = list;
        ddlSalesRep_F.DataValueField = "EmpId";
        ddlSalesRep_F.DataTextField = "EmpName";
        ddlSalesRep_F.DataBind();
        row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(ddlSalesRep_F);

        TextBox txtPotsUpfrontPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtPotsUpfrontPercentage_F.ID = "txtPotsUpfrontPercentage_F";
        txtPotsUpfrontPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtPotsUpfrontPercentage_F.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        txtPotsUpfrontPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtPotsUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtPotsUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(txtPotsUpfrontPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtPotsUnitPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtPotsUnitPercentage_F.ID = "txtPotsUnitPercentage_F";
        txtPotsUnitPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtPotsUnitPercentage_F.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        txtPotsUnitPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtPotsUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtPotsUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(txtPotsUnitPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtPotsResPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtPotsResPercentage_F.ID = "txtPotsResPercentage_F";
        txtPotsResPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtPotsResPercentage_F.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        txtPotsResPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtPotsResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtPotsResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidPOTS(this)");
        row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(txtPotsResPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtLdUpfrontPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtLdUpfrontPercentage_F.ID = "txtLdUpfrontPercentage_F";
        txtLdUpfrontPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtLdUpfrontPercentage_F.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DDDCE7"); ;
        txtLdUpfrontPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtLdUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtLdUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(txtLdUpfrontPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtLdUnitPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtLdUnitPercentage_F.ID = "txtLdUnitPercentage_F";
        txtLdUnitPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtLdUnitPercentage_F.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DDDCE7"); ;
        txtLdUnitPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtLdUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtLdUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(txtLdUnitPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtLdResPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtLdResPercentage_F.ID = "txtLdResPercentage_F";
        txtLdResPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtLdResPercentage_F.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DDDCE7"); ;
        txtLdResPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtLdResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtLdResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(txtLdResPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtAdsUpfrontPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtAdsUpfrontPercentage_F.ID = "txtAdsUpfrontPercentage_F";
        txtAdsUpfrontPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtAdsUpfrontPercentage_F.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        txtAdsUpfrontPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtAdsUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtAdsUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txtAdsUpfrontPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtAdsUnitPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtAdsUnitPercentage_F.ID = "txtAdsUnitPercentage_F";
        txtAdsUnitPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtAdsUnitPercentage_F.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        txtAdsUnitPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtAdsUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtAdsUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[8].Controls.Add(txtAdsUnitPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtAdsResPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtAdsResPercentage_F.ID = "txtAdsResPercentage_F";
        txtAdsResPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtAdsResPercentage_F.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        txtAdsResPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtAdsResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtAdsResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[9].Controls.Add(txtAdsResPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtBroadbandUpfrontPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtBroadbandUpfrontPercentage_F.ID = "txtBroadbandUpfrontPercentage_F";
        txtBroadbandUpfrontPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtBroadbandUpfrontPercentage_F.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DDDCE7"); ;
        txtBroadbandUpfrontPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtBroadbandUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtBroadbandUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[10].Controls.Add(txtBroadbandUpfrontPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtBroadbandUnitPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtBroadbandUnitPercentage_F.ID = "txtBroadbandUnitPercentage_F";
        txtBroadbandUnitPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtBroadbandUnitPercentage_F.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DDDCE7"); ;
        txtBroadbandUnitPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtBroadbandUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtBroadbandUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[11].Controls.Add(txtBroadbandUnitPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtBroadbandResPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtBroadbandResPercentage_F.ID = "txtBroadbandResPercentage_F";
        txtBroadbandResPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtBroadbandResPercentage_F.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DDDCE7"); ;
        txtBroadbandResPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtBroadbandResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtBroadbandResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[12].Controls.Add(txtBroadbandResPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtLdCanUpfrontPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtLdCanUpfrontPercentage_F.ID = "txtLdCanUpfrontPercentage_F";
        txtLdCanUpfrontPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtLdCanUpfrontPercentage_F.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        txtLdCanUpfrontPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtLdCanUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtLdCanUpfrontPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[13].Controls.Add(txtLdCanUpfrontPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtLdCanUnitPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtLdCanUnitPercentage_F.ID = "txtLdCanUnitPercentage_F";
        txtLdCanUnitPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtLdCanUnitPercentage_F.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        txtLdCanUnitPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtLdCanUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtLdCanUnitPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[14].Controls.Add(txtLdCanUnitPercentage_F);

        TextBox txtLdCanResPercentage_F = new TextBox();
        txtLdCanResPercentage_F.ID = "txtLdCanResPercentage_F";
        txtLdCanResPercentage_F.MaxLength = 6;
        txtLdCanResPercentage_F.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        txtLdCanResPercentage_F.Width = new Unit(50);
        txtLdCanResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isValidPercentageKey(event)");
        txtLdCanResPercentage_F.Attributes.Add("onblur", "return isValidNumber(this)");
        row.Cells[15].Controls.Add(txtLdCanResPercentage_F);
        #endregion

        grdview.Controls[0].Controls.Add(row);

        }
    }
```

This method is adding new row to the grid and based on number of times clicked it would add new row to grid. The only issue is when user enters value in the row fields how to fetch those values of new added rows.

```
    if (ViewState["ExtraFooter_Primary"] == null || ViewState   ["ExtraFooter_Primary"].ToString() == "-1")
            {
                ViewState["ExtraFooter_Primary"] = "-1";


                Session.Add(ConstantSession.EmployeeList, employeeList);

                DropDownList ddlSalesRep = gvPrimaryGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlSalesRep_F") as DropDownList;
                ddlSalesRep.DataSource = employeeList;
                ddlSalesRep.DataValueField = "SMPID";
                ddlSalesRep.DataTextField = "SMPName";
                ddlSalesRep.DataBind();
            }

            Button btnAddPrimaryRep = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnAddPrimaryRep");
            btnAddPrimaryRep.Visible = Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["ExtraFooter_Primary"]) > 3 ? false : true;

            ViewState["ExtraFooter_Primary"] = (Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["ExtraFooter_Primary"]) + 1).ToString();
            CreateExtraFooter(gvPrimaryGrid, employeeList, Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["ExtraFooter_Primary"]));
```